# He can eat little/some/very spicy

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

> He can eat a little spicy.
>
> He can eat some spicy.
>
> He can eat spicy.
>
> He can eat very spicy.

How to describe different spicy level that can accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spicy is an adjective. We usually don't eat adjectives. Try something like:

> He can eat very spicy food.
>
> He can't eat spicy food.
>
> He can't handle spicy food.
>
> He loves spicy food.
>
> This food is too spicy for him.
>
> This food isn't spicy enough for him.

As for levels of spiciness here are a few examples that you could run with:

> Not at all spicy.
>
> Mildly spicy.
>
> Somewhat spicy.
>
> Moderately spicy.
>
> Very spicy.
>
> Extremely spicy.
>
> Painfully spicy.
>
> Dangerously spicy.

Answer (score 3):

None of them are correct. Spicy is an **adjective**, but you're using it as a **noun**.

To fix this, you can use the noun *spiciness*. You should also use a different verb than *eat* (because you don't eat "spiciness"); [*tolerate*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/tolerate?q=tolerate) is acceptable:

> He can tolerate a little spiciness.
>
> He can tolerate some spiciness.
>
> He can tolerate spiciness.
>
> He can tolerate a lot of spiciness.